Unable to do Roto-Reflection of methane molecule
I am trying to plot the methane molecule and it's roto-reflection. But for some reason it's not working. The output is like
Here is the image: 
Here is the code:
  Molecule[{"C", "H", "H", "H"}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"], 
    Bond[{1, 3}, "Single"], Bond[{1, 4}, "Single"]}, 
   AtomCoordinates -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {-0.5, Sqrt[3]/2, 
      0}, {-0.5, -Sqrt[3]/2, 0}}];
sigmaHPlane = 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Blue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{-1, 0, -0.5}, {1, 0, -0.5}, {0, 1, -0.5}}]}];
C3Axis = 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}]}];
rotationMatrix = RotationMatrix[2  Pi/3, {0, 0, 1}]; 
rotatedCoordinates = 
  rotationMatrix . # & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {-0.5, Sqrt[3]/2, 
     0}, {-0.5, -Sqrt[3]/2, 0}};
reflectedCoordinates = {#[[1]], #[[2]], 2*(-1) - #[[3]]} & /@ 
   rotatedCoordinates;
transformedMethene = 
  Molecule[{"C", "H", "H", "H"}, {Bond[{1, 2}, "Single"], 
    Bond[{1, 3}, "Single"], Bond[{1, 4}, "Single"]}, 
   AtomCoordinates -> reflectedCoordinates];
Show[MoleculePlot3D[methene, AtomLabels -> "AtomIndex", 
  AtomLabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16, Blue]], 
 MoleculePlot3D[transformedMethene, AtomLabels -> "AtomIndex", 
  AtomLabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontSize -> 16, Red]], sigmaHPlane, C3Axis, 
 Boxed -> False]

can someone help?, The 5th atom should be pointing down for the reflection.

Your code produce an error. Please check.

The route I would take is something like MoleculeModify[methane,{"TransformAtomCoordinates",ReflectionTransform[<you fill in the rest here>]}] like here

ReplacementTranform[{0,0,1},{0,0,-0.5}] it gives me error.
